# jquery sortable moved item floating far away

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using JQuery Sortable.
It works fine, but I have this weird thing where sometimes the item I'm moving is floating very far away from my list, and usually in a different spot all the time.
Ideally, I'd like to hide it while it's being moved, since I have a space highlighting where it would land anyway.

How can I hide it while being moved, or is there a better solution?

[image]

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I have. I can't reproduce the problem at the jsFiddle, so I suppose it's something unique to my website.